# creating a data base for staff time table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timetable

i wana create a database  for staff timetable!!
my attributes are,

```
StaffTimeTable - TimetableID(pk),StaffID,periods,day.
```

per day a school has 8 periods(where a staff need to attend) one staff can have only one timetableID.

My problem is how can i create a database with one timetableid for 5days!!

an exmaple

```
TimeTableID    StaffID  Day     period1 p2 p3     p4  p5   p6   p7   p8 

stt001         st001  Monday  maths      physics
```

My Question is How can i insert the Tuesday TimeTable(for the same time table id) ??

If answered its most appreciable !! :)

Comment: Learning about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) would answer your question for you.

Comment: you should have one timetableid for each person by day.. as in each day should be a new row. you can have the same id on more than one row if it is a unique id for a person... so like person a on day 1 (row1) has the same timetableid as on day 2 (row2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should make a few tables for this.

[SEE IT IN ACTION!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/541b92/2)

## SETUP:

```
CREATE TABLE periods (
   id int, 
   period varchar(55)
);
```

this table would look something like this

```
id       period
1        'maths'
2        'physics'
3        'english'
... etc
```

you should also have a table for the days like so

```
CREATE TABLE day_of_week (
    id int,
    day varchar(55)
);
```

this would look something like this.

```
id             day
1              'Sunday'
2              'Monday'
3              'Tuesday'
4              'Wednesday'
.... etc.
```

you should have a staff table like so

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
    id int,
    staff_name varchar(55)
);
```

this table would look something like this.

```
id            staff_name
1             Mary
2             John
..... etc
```

NOW you need to have a connecting table.

```
CREATE TABLE StaffTimeTable (
    id int, -- this is the pk
    staffID int,
    periodID int,
    dayID int
);
```

## NOTE:

each of these id's are the foreign key to the primary keys in your other tables...
also all of the primary key id's should be auto incremented.

## COMBINE IT ALL

```
SELECT t.id, s.staff_name, d.day_name, p.period
FROM StaffTimeTable t
JOIN staff s on s.id = t.staffID
JOIN day_of_week d on d.id =  t.dayID
JOIN periods p on p.id = t.periodID
ORDER BY t.id;
```

Comment: @Trax a few extra notes. you need to make each id auto incremented.. you can make a drop down in html for each field.. like the staff person... the day, the period.. then when each field is selected and or filled out (if you don't use a dropdown) then you can insert into the StaffTimeTable table a new row with the id's from the other tables.. those can be pulled out by what the user selects... if you want me to explain that better i can just let me know

Comment: @John-I understood about the auto increment. If there is any further issues, i hope you wont mind me if i contact you.

Comment: @Trax no problem.. if you need more help just comment on here with your email address and I can email you for further assistance :)

Comment: hello john:) your design was so help full. i need some further assistant in some SQL Queries. ill be glad if i can get your help to finish my project.

Comment: But how do you manage the timings? Like in a day there could be 6-7 periods and how to know which period comes under what time?

Comment: Well the staff time table has a period id. I would assume you enter records as needed for all the fields.. if you need something more explicit then maybe add another table to track the periods in a given day